# Redirect htacces links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some links for not having duplicate content on google

The links are like this.. www.example.ro/adidasi_dama.php?page=1

I made the rewrite rule to .. www.example.ro/adidasi-dama/pagina-1/

with this code..

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)([-_]){1}([a-zA-Z]+)/pagina-([0-9]+)/$ $1_$3.php?page=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)([-_]){1}([a-zA-Z]+)/$ $1_$3.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/pagina-([0-9]+)/$ /$1.php?page=$2
```

But now... both versions are working... .. i want to automaticaly redirect from 1st link to second... but i need it for all my pages..

i have many links for example

- www.example.ro/noutati.php?page=1
- www.example.ro/adidasi_fete.php?page=1
- www.example.ro/pantofi_barbati.php?page=1

  ...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the same htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z_]+)\.php\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %1:%2 (.+)_(.+):(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2/pagina-%3/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z_]+)\.php\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/pagina-%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z_]+)\.php(\ |$)
RewriteCond %1 (.+)_(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([a-zA-Z_]+)\.php(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There is a problem... it redirects me to /sandale_dama/pagina-2/
but i need to /sandale-dama/pagina-2/ ... the diference is thist - with _.. what i need to change ?

Comment: @user1483138 going to need to make those special cases like you did in your rules. See my edit.